# Devexpress LookupEdit.Text sometimes can be changed

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have noticed that sometimes it is possible to set a LookUpEdit.Text property in code, contrary to the DevExpress documentation. Has anyone else experienced this? If I could rely on setter to have no effect I could delete this code without fear of side effects. Do I really have to investigate dependencies for all methods that set a LookUpEdit.Text property?

Answer (score 0):

I think it works on `EditValue` rather that `Text` and I would without a doubt not use `Text` to do any manipulations on the `LookUpEdit`.